# prevent AssertionError: daemonic processes are not allowed to have children

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pool

I am running stuff using `Pool`/`multiprocessing`.
Whenever I call Pool again (nested) within one of the child processes of the main process, this error is raised?

```
prevent multiprocessing gives AssertionError: daemonic processes are not allowed to have children
```

Is there a way to detect if code is running already part of a `Pool`, to be able to prevent this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can get the current process instance and check whether it is daemonic or not:

```
from multiprocessing import process

print(f"is current process daemonic: {process.current_process().daemon}")
```

**Output**:

```
is current process daemonic: False
```

Inside a pool, that `.daemon` property will be `True`